# Error when adding parameter for reportsviewer VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, report

I am new to VB.NET and I'm trying to add a parameter for filtering a reportsviewer. When I added the Client_Name_, the following error pops up -

[image]

How can it be solved? I scoured everywhere for solutions but to no avail.

Comment: Please add the full query you have written. Otherwise it is very difficult to find the bug.

Comment: I just started adding a query. This is the first query that I attempted to create.

Comment: Is there semiclone (;) is a factor ?

Comment: There's no semicolon

Comment: try WHERE Issued_By = ?. If that doesn't give the syntax error then it might be misinterpreting the _ character before the = Is there a reason you appended the _ on your column names? Just seems hard to read.